# Does the gmail app stop syncing once the "Low on space" message appears?

Tags: gmail, internal-storage

Based on casual observation and anecdotal evidence it appears to me that once the "Low on space" message appears in the status bar the gmail app stops syncing and stops notifying me of new emails.

Can anyone confirm whether this is the case?

Comment: But you can still watch a video over one hour long in YouTube. So, what's the logic behind this? Planned Obsolescence again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you are in fact *really* low on space then gmail stops syncing. You might also stop receiving SMS's and other data until you have made some space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you be able to expand a bit more on that, i.e. is there a particular API signal or a percentage threshhold of available internal memory that triggers this behaviour?

Comment: @snth sorry, pass...

Comment: On the Milestone with Android 2.2 I have observed that as soon as the Low Memory icon appears the phone stops to sync contacts, gmail, calandar, etc. Moreover applications installation and updates from the Market are failing.

Comment: But you can still watch a video over one hour long in YouTube. So, what's the logic behind this? Planned Obsolescence again?